# Adding text to list output

Tags: powershell

I need to format, add text to, a list of files I am getting using Powershell.  I can simply use the following script to get my list of files:

```
Get-ChildItem("c:\path") | where {$_.Length -eq 0} | select name
```

This works well returning a list of file names:

> file1.txt
>   file2.txt
>   file2.txt

What I am trying to do is add additional text to the output so it looks more like this:

> 'file1.txt',
>   'file2.txt',
>   'file3.txt',

This I am finding to be more difficult than it should be.  I tried this:

```
$l = Get-ChildItem("c:\path") | where {$_.Length -eq 0} | select name | foreach($_) { "'$_,"}
```

This doesn't quite do it, as the field name is added to the output:

> '@{Name=file1.txt}.Name',
>   '@{Name=file2.txt}.Name',
>   '@{Name=file3.txt}.Name',

Is there a way to format this better or remove the object information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. Use the `-expandproperty` parameter for `select-object` to get the property as a simple array of strings.

```
$l = Get-ChildItem("c:\path") |
    where {$_.Length -eq 0} |
    select -expandproperty name | foreach($_) { "'$_,"}
```

Comment: I selected this method as it provides the most control over which fields you may want to select from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$l = Get-ChildItem("D:\Test") | where { $_.Length -eq 0 } | %{"'$_',"}
```

Comment: Strange, this does work.  Why is $_ in the last part only returning the Name and not all the fields?  I would assume it still contains everything, or is it only returning the first field?

Comment: What does the % do?  e.g. %{"'$_',"}

Comment: % is alias for "foreach" cmdlet

Comment: I think $_ works because there might be some ToString method which is called when you are providing value in string.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got V3 or better you can do it this way:

```
@((Get-ChildItem c:\path  | where Length -eq 0).name) -match '\S'| foreach { "'$_'," }
```

Comment: Issue with this is that '', is returned if there are no files returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$l = Get-ChildItem("c:\path") | where {$_.Length -eq 0} | select $_.Name | foreach { "'$_'," }
```